# how to make a folder undeletable?

Tags: c#

How can I make a folder undeletable?

Alternatively, how can I request Windows user to give pass for deleting it.

Regards.

Comment: how about using NTFS ACL? But this should handled from superuser.com

Comment: @Oliver: given the C# tag, I assume he wants to know how to do it in code...

Answer (score 7):

You use the [Directory.SetAccessControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol.aspx) method. There's an example on that link, but here it is just in case:

```
public static void AddDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, 
                      FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
{
    // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

    // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the 
    // current security settings.
    DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

    // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
    dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                    Rights,
                                                    ControlType));

    // Set the new access settings.
    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
}
```

Comment: what does it do ?

Does this code make a file or folder undeletable ?

Comment: This code in particular does not do that, but the `SetAccessControl` method allows you to modify the permissions on the directory so that only users you choose will be able to delete it (or read it's contents or whatever you want to do). This code is just an example of how you use `SetAccessControl`.

Comment: no, it a function to add securty to a folder (hence the name AddDirectorySecurity) Here  you can see the rights you can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to use ADSI: MSDN has a sample on how to set file and folder permissions on NTFS drives using C#:

> **[How to programmatically set NTFS file system folder permissions by using Active Directory Service Interfaces in Microsoft Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899553)**

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,

google.com for "make folder undeletable"

gives me: 
http://www.techtipsgeek.com/secure-private-folders-making-inaccessible-undeletable/104/

What is your target OS ? You might be able to set folder permissions in the newer versions of Windows.

Comment: This article talks only about the fact that a folder named `lpt1` cannot be deleted from Explorer.

Comment: ouch :-/ You got me. that's what happens to you with tabbed browsing. I'll fix that in a second.